# XML layout unable to display view properly

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, admob

This is my xml layout,I'm trying to place the Adview below the recycler view so the ads do not overlap any of the items on the recycler view but as of now the Adview is not shown.How exactly should i place the items such that the toolbar is at the top and below that the recycler view with the swipe refresh listener and below that the AdView and all of them should be visisble on the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_recipe_results2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textIcons" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" />
```

Comment: Hi jude,You can try Relative layout instead of use linear layout. In your code when you fill info in recycle view their is no limit of height, Using relative layout you can set fix positions of attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to make the `linearlayout` divided by weights

convert your `XML` layout to the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_recipe_results2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:titleTextColor="@color/textIcons" />

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/pull_to_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadingEdge="none" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" />
```

it will works for you...

just add to the `SwipeRefreshLayout`

```
android:layout_weight="1"
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

and add that to `RecyclerView`

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

hope works with u :)

Answer (score 0):

Use Frame Layout instead of Linear Layout. Frame Layout fixes the position of every view.